# Field Calculator decimal places - how can I limit them?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, decimal-points

I've added a new column to an attribute table and performed an operation with the field calculator to populate the new column. The result is a column with a percentage. My problem isn't major but I can't seem to limit the number of decimal places so that I just have solid numbers. Right now I have 13 places after the decimal, I would like it to be 0.

Answer (score 6):

If you create a new field, make it "integer" instead of "real" if you don't want any values after the comma anyway.

Alternatively, use the "toint" function in "conversions".

Comment: Excellent! Always a great help :)

Answer (score -1):

Open the field calculator, click on `new virtual field`, assign decimal data type and then use the following code

```
count("the column you want to limit", 2)
```

Your new virtual field will be having the same value as your decimal field, but will be limited to 2 decimal numbers.

Answer (score -3):

You don't do that in the field calculator, try the properties of that field, there is a button, num or ... That will allow you to set rounding and precision.

Comment: No you can't change those.